# Hello...why this function doesnt work for n=0?

Tags: c, function, recursion, binary

I have to write a recursive function in C to convert a number from decimal to binary.
This is the prototype we were given
`void dec_to_binary(int n)`.

My code:

```
void dec_to_binary(int n)
{
    // base case: if the number is 0, return
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    // recursive case: divide the number by 2 and call the function again
    dec_to_binary(n / 2);
    // print the remainder (which will be 0 or 1)
    printf("%d", n % 2);
}
```

Why doesn't it work when `n` is 0 ?

Comment: If `n==0` you simply `return` without printing anything.

Comment: The first line of the function explains it: It immediately returns in that case.

Comment: if i say to return 0...then it doesnt work for other inputs and it only work for 0

Comment: maybe you need to enclose this function in another function, and in that function you should check if the number is 0, then print 0 otherwise call the recursive function

Comment: You should add `printf("%d", 0);` before the `return`

Comment: @jvx8ss but then there will be trailing zero for non zero inputs wouldnt it?

Comment: jvx8ss i tried that....it makes the program work for 0 only....but then it doesnt work for n>0

Comment: check the answer i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not print anything when it is zero because it returns immediately. Perhaps you could check if input is zero before calling the function, like this:

```
void dec_to_binary_recursive(int n)
{
    // base case: if the number is 0, return
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    // recursive case: divide the number by 2 and call the function again
    dec_to_binary_recursive(n / 2);
    // print the remainder (which will be 0 or 1)
    printf("%d", n % 2);
}

void dec_to_binary(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        printf("%d", 0);
    }
    else
    {
        dec_to_binary_recursive(n);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this does not support negative numbers, and there probably a better way

Comment: `printf("0");` is the same as `printf("%d", 0);` and has the potential to be faster

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to make an way that does not need an wrapper function or a second argument. works with negatives too

```c
void dec_to_binary(int n) {
    if ((unsigned int)n > 1)
        dec_to_binary((unsigned int)n/2);
    printf("%u", (unsigned int)n % 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted above your current `dec_to_binary` function immediately returns and does nothing when the input is 0.

You can solve the problem without adding a function,
by having a base case for the recursion for both 0 and 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dec_to_binary(unsigned int n)
{
    // base case (0 or 1):
    if (n <= 1u)
    {
        printf("%u", n);
        return;
    }
    // recursive case:
    dec_to_binary(n / 2);
    printf("%u", n % 2);
}

int main()
{
    dec_to_binary(0);    printf("\n");
    dec_to_binary(1);    printf("\n");
    dec_to_binary(2);    printf("\n");
    dec_to_binary(7);    printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
10
111
```

Note that this solution is for non negative values only, so I changed the input type to `unsigned`.